# Javascript: How to pass a single element from the array to a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have an array:

```
var animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'duck']
```

And want to pass only specified elements by index from the array (not the whole array) to a function:

```
function foobar(animals[1], animals[3])
{
     some function...
}
```

This doesn't work. The debugging tools are expecting a different syntax.

Comment: array index in function declaration?

Comment: Why was my comment asking to disregard my flag removed from this post? The flag was "declined," I left the comment specifically so that would not happen.

Answer (score 3):

```
function foobar(animal)
{
     some function...
}

foobar(animals[1]); // send dog to foobar - js arrays start at 0
```

or more than one (passing an array means only one parameter needed)

```
function foobar(subanimals)
{
     some function... 
}

foobar([animals[1],animals[3]]); // send dog and duck to foobar as an array
```

Lastly if you do not want to care if you receive an array or a single item

```
function foobar(subanimals)
{
     if (!Array.isArray(subanimals)) subanimals=[subanimals]; //force array

     some function... 
}


foobar(animals[2]); // send ONLY horse
```

Also look at [array slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

In the last two functions you can do

```
  for (var i=0;i<subanimals.length;i++) {
    if (subanimals[i]=="duck") alert("fowl");
    else if (subanimals[i]=="horse") alert("ungulate");
    else alert("Neither fowl nor horse");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! On your example 2, how do I work inside the function with `dog` and `duck` if I don't know that the values are dog and duck? The array is dynamically generated on page load, in reality I don't know the value names, yet still need to use them in the function.

Answer (score 3):

```
function foobar(a, b)
{
     some function...
}

foobar(animals[1], animals[3]);
```